# how to set tileList component's font to be anti-aliased action script 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-v3-components

I have a tileList component and i was wondering how one might go about antialiasing the font inside of each label. I have the font embedded using:

```
leftList.setRendererStyle("embedFonts", true);
```

I have tried targeting the label specifically with no luck so far.

did not work.

```
var theTextField:TextField = leftList.label;
leftList.antiAliasType = "advanced";
```

anyone have and suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set a text format also, and make sure the font you're using is embedded.

e.g.

```
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Verdana",12,0x990000);
leftList.setRendererStyle('textFormat',format);
leftList.setRendererStyle('embedFonts',true);
```

HTH